# GridView RowUpdating does not get the new values

Tags: c#, events, gridview

I have at the moment a problem with `RowUpdating` from a `GridView` and accessing the new values. I add a dynamic `DataTable` to my `GridView.DataSource` and bind to it. If I use the update button nothing happens and I get back to my normal `GridView`.
Here's my Page_Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control test = GetPostBackControl(Page);
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if ((test.ID == "SumbitSearch") && (DropDownListFrom.Text != "") && (DropDownListTo.Text != "") && (SearchField.Text != ""))
        {
            DataTable result = new DataTable();
            string from = null;
            string to = null;

            switch (DropDownListFrom.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    from = DropDownListFrom.Items[0].Value;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    from = DropDownListFrom.Items[1].Value;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    from = DropDownListFrom.Items[2].Value;
                    break;
            }

            switch (DropDownListTo.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    to = DropDownListTo.Items[0].Value;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    to = DropDownListTo.Items[1].Value;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    to = DropDownListTo.Items[2].Value;
                    break;
            }

            result = LoadGridView(from, to);
            GridViewResult.DataSource = result;
            Session["Result"] = result;
            GridViewResult.DataBind();

            GridViewResult.Columns[0].Visible = true;
            GridViewResult.Columns[1].Visible = true;

            GridViewResult.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Width = Unit.Pixel(110);
            GridViewResult.HeaderRow.Cells[1].Width = Unit.Pixel(60);
            GridViewResult.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text = "Nach: " + from;
            GridViewResult.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text = "Von: " + to;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewResult.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Later, the `GridView` should only appear if both `DropDownList`s are used and the `SearchField` is not empty. I also check if the button which execute the `PostBack` is the search button.

Here is what I added to the `RowUpdating EventHandler`:

```
protected void TaskGridViewResult_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewResult.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["Result"];
    for (int i = 0; i < GridViewResult.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        DataControlFieldCell cell = GridViewResult.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i] as DataControlFieldCell;
        GridViewResult.Columns[i].ExtractValuesFromCell(e.NewValues, cell, DataControlRowState.Edit, true);
    }

    GridViewResult.EditIndex = -1;
    DataBind();
}
```

What is going wrong?

**Last Change:** More Information (@jwiscarson)

I’m sorry, I was in hurry. I will try to give you a better view.
In that project, the users could select 2 categories, enter a search string and the result will show in a GridView. The RowUpdating stuff is for the "admin user".
Here is my problem, if the "admin user" click on edit, change the value of the cell and execute the update, the value would not changed in the `DataTable`.

> Without seeing your markup, it's hard for […] based on some search
>   criteria?

I add `GridViewResult` as markup in my project.

> I'm also not sure why […] within that button's Click event.

Yes, I thought that too! But I read in a blog it is better to put the code into Page_Load(), if you are working with `GridViews`. I believed him. Is it okay, to put that code into the click event handler from my button? I'm very new to that. I just could read lots of blogs, msdn and ask here.

`TaskGridViewResult_RowUpdating` is also added as markup to my code. Could I also create this and the GridView in my `CreateChildControls()`?

As markups I have two `DropDownLists`, a `TextBox` for the search string, a search submit `Button` and the `GridView`.

At the moment, i havent the exactly code here but the `GridView` looks like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    OnRowUpdating="TaskGridViewResult_RowUpdating">
    <!-- // More of that... -->
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I could give you more details tomorrow.

Maybe I forgot this. Before I could click the update button and execute the `TaskGridViewResult_RowUpdating` event to change the value of the cell. I set the row editable with:

```
 protected void TaskGridViewResult _RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
    GridViewResult.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    DataBind();
  }
```

**Next Change:**
I added to the GridView few `TemplateField`s like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="test">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("from") %>'>   </asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("from") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is it, I have access to the new value with:

```
string test = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

in `TaskGridViewResult_RowUpdating()`

Now, I just have to bind the template dynamically with the values from the dropdown list, and that’s it I think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoo boy.

You didn't ask this in your question, but you've written some smelly code here. I'll try to address your question, but I'm also going through some of the other problems here.

Without seeing your markup, it's hard for me to tell if you've created `GridViewResult` programmatically or if it's in your markup as well. I'm not exactly sure what `TaskGridViewResult` is either -- is this an event for `GridViewResult`? Do you have another `GridView` on your page, and you want to show `GridViewResult` based on some search criteria?

I'm also not sure why you put all of your `GridView` binding code in `Page_Load`. I see that you're checking `GetPostBackControl` to find the control that caused the `PostBack` -- this is a code smell. If your users have to click a specific "Search" button, you should isolate your `GridView` binding code within that button's `Click` event.

Anyway, as to `TaskGridViewResult_RowUpdating`:

It looks like you're trying to update `GridViewResult`'s old values to the new values by setting its `DataSource` and then iterating through its data. You can't do that. What happens when you change your `RowUpdating` event to:

```
protected void TaskGridViewResult_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewResult.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["Result"];
    GridViewResult.DataBind();
}
```

Now, other asides:

Your `switch` statements are code smells. `DropDownList`s expose a property called `SelectedValue` -- if you have some default value that isn't a valid selection (like the first option in your `DropDownList`), then you can change your original code from:

```
if ((test.ID == "SumbitSearch") && (DropDownListFrom.Text != "") && (DropDownListTo.Text != "") && (SearchField.Text != ""))
{
    string from = string.Empty;
    string to = string.Empty;

    switch (DropDownListFrom.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            from = DropDownListFrom.Items[0].Value;
            break;
        /* other cases */
    }

    switch (DropDownListTo.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            to = DropDownListTo.Items[0].Value;
            break;
        /* other cases */
    }
    /* snip */
}
```

to:

```
if (test.ID == "SubmitSearch" && DropDownListFrom.SelectedIndex > 0 && DropDownListTo.SelectedIndex > 0 && SearchField.Text != "")
{
    string from = DropDownListFrom.SelectedValue;
    string to = DropDownListTo.SelectedValue;

    /* snip */
}
```

If you can, please post your markup. I can offer you some more specific help or advice if I can tell what `Controls` you have on your page, and how they interact.

**Edit:** I should also add that you should get in the habit of using `String.IsNullOrEmpty(string variable)`, rather than comparing to `""`. Although this isn't as big of a problem when you're referencing the text from web controls, getting in the habit now will prevent you from serious headaches and inefficiently checking for null and empty later. If you're in .NET 4.0, you should have access to `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`, which is (in my opinion) more useful on the web, where users are more likely to try to enter junk data.

**Edit 2:** In response to your additional details above:

In your `RowUpdating` event, you need to pull the new values out of the front-end controls, and then re-bind your data. It looks like your source code is pretty close to the MSDN source code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx). The difference between your code and the code on MSDN is:
 - The MSDN code takes the new data from the edited row and updates the appropriate data in the `Session` variable with that new data.
 - The MSDN code has a `BindData()` function -- I'm not sure if this is what your `DataBind()` function is, however.
 - The MSDN code updates the `GridView` by re-binding the `GridView` to the appropriate data in the `Session`.

Frankly, I have some issues with the MSDN code. I really, **really** hate seeing code like: `dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Id"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;` To me, this is garbage, because it's so highly coupled to the order of your cells.

If I had written the code, I would explicitly create all the front-end controls and use a binding command (if you aren't familiar, it looks like `<%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "FieldName") %>` in the markup -- see more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.aspx)). Then, in my `RowUpdating` event, I'd use `e.Row.FindControl("controlName")`, and update the `Session` data from that.

Honestly, if your back-end data isn't changing on a regular basis, I don't see any reason to programmatically create your `GridView`s. It over-complicates your C# code to go through these steps yourself when you can just set it up once in your markup. If you need to hide one `GridView`, you can always set its `Visible` property to `false`. Then, when you're ready to show it, set `Visible = true`.

Finally, I've spread my `GridView` code across so many events (button clicks, `RowDataBound` events from other `GridViews`/`Repeaters`, etc.), I can't imagine why someone would suggest that you only put it in `Page_Load`.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! Look at the **Last Change:** in my question, here I added additional information’s. I didn't know about `.Empty` and `IsNullOrEmpty`... Thanks!!!

Comment: How should I create all front-end controls in the markup? The column depense on the selected value from the dropdown, I dont know the both selected items at the beginning. Additional, I think the main problem is, that I loose the dynamically `TextBox`s at the `PostBach`, right? I click on edit, now i could change the values. After that i click on update, and the `PostBack` occur. Greetz

Comment: Okay, I made stride. See my **Next Change:** edit. How could i bind the items to the selected value from the dropbox? Greetz.

Comment: Okay, everything works. I just changes the SQL Query with `SELECT Ident, test AS "BindName1", ...`. Now I could use fixed bin names. Thanks for your greate help! Greetz.